# Expectation of Uniform Distributions

Tags: statistics

Given $X = \operatorname{Uniform}(0, 4)$ distribution where the distribution is **continuous**.

Using the definition for $\operatorname E(X)$

\begin{align}
& \operatorname E(X) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^\infty xP(X\in dx) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\frac 1 {4-0} \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 4 x \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \text{undefined?}
\end{align}

But the textbook is like $E(X)=\frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{0+4}{2}$ ?

**Definition of $E(X)$ for continous distributions:**

[image]

Comment: You forgot to restrict the integral's range to the support of $X$, which is $[0,4]$.

Comment: Or another way of stating @ParclyTaxel's point is that $P(X \in dx)$ is zero outside the domain $[0,4]$, so your integral is very well defined.

Comment: But the definition of $E(X)$ doesn't say $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)f(x)dx$, it says from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density is $f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac 1 4 & \text{if } 0<x<4, \\  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$

Therefore
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 x\cdot0\,dx + \int_0^4 x\cdot\frac 1 4\, dx + \int_4^\infty x\cdot0\,dx.
\end{align}

You should never write $\text{“}{= \text{undefined.''}}$ You should say that something *is* undefined, not that it is equal to something called "undefined". This is the "is" of predication, not the "is" of equality.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering why everyone was telling me to restrict the range without giving me a reason. I knew using the definition of E(X) should work.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus "without giving me a reason" Actually, users Parcly Taxel, David G. Stork, and Joaquin San all "gave you a reason" but, for unknown motives, **you did not listen**.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake on the definition of your density. The correct density only asigns positive values to points on $(0,4)$, meaning
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot  \mathbf{1}_{(0,4)} (x)$$